# JSON OBJECTS in Objective C

Tags: json, xcode6, nsmutablearray

I need to create a json object in the following format in XCode and I've been using XCode 6.

```
   string json = @"{'user': 'Teva',
                    'password': 'abc123',
                    'SourceID':1,
                    'SiteID':1,
                    'VariableID':1,
                    'MethodID':1,
                    'values':[
                        ['2015-01-29 21:00:00',133.0],
                        ['2015-01-29 22:00:00',134.0]
                    ]}";
```

I tried NSDictonary approach. However, I'm getting the following output:
This is my code.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
       [super viewDidLoad];
       NSError *error;
       NSDictionary *jsonDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                @"user", @"Teva",
                                @"password", @"abc123",
                                @"SourceID", @"1",
                                @"SiteID", @"1",
                                @"VariableID", @"1",
                                @"MethodID", @"1",
                                @"values", @"[2015-01-29 21:00:00, 134.0], [2015-01-29 22:00:00, 135.0]",
                               nil];


NSMutableArray * arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

[arr addObject:jsonDictionary];

NSData *jsonData2 = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:arr options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];

NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData2 encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSLog(@"jsonData as string:\n%@", jsonString);
}
```

I got the following output:

```
jsonData as string:
[
 {
   "abc123" : "password",
   "1" : "VariableID",
   "Teva" : "user",
   "[2015-01-29 21:00:00, 134.0], [2015-01-29 22:00:00, 135.0]" :      "values",
  "campaignCategory" : "MethodID",
  "actionDate" : "SiteID",
  "dueDate" : "SourceID"
 }
]
```

Anyone help me to get the right json using objective C. Thanks for your help!

Comment: This is a string, and so that's what you end up with: `@"[2015-01-29 21:00:00, 134.0], [2015-01-29 22:00:00, 135.0]"`

Comment: (If you want an array, don't enclose it in quotes.  But note that the time values *are* strings, and need to be `@"` quoted, and the float values need `@()` around them.)

Comment: (And note that you have your keys and values backwards.  Read the name of the method that creates the dictionary VERY carefully.)

Comment: Would you please show me the way I need to create dictionary to get the above output.

Comment: I change the function as follows:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the answer that I was hoping to get. I hope it might be useful to someone.

```
-(void)saveDataValue
{
NSMutableArray *matchArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"2015-01-29 21:00:00", @(134.0), nil];

NSMutableDictionary *contentDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
[contentDictionary setValue:@"Teva" forKey:@"user"];
[contentDictionary setValue:@"abc123" forKey:@"password"];
[contentDictionary setValue:@"1" forKey:@"SourceID"];
[contentDictionary setValue:@"1" forKey:@"SiteID"];
[contentDictionary setValue:@"1" forKey:@"VariableID"];
[contentDictionary setValue:@"1" forKey:@"MethodID"];
[contentDictionary setValue:matchArray forKey:@"values"];
NSData *data = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:contentDictionary options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:nil];
NSString *jsonStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"jsonData as string:\n%@", jsonStr);
}
```

HAPPY CODING... :)